# Is this "pattern" for "hijaxing" forms reliable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, sails.js, hijax

**Definition of Hijax:**

> Hijax is a term for the application of progressive enhancement to
>   AJAX. It is also known as 'Simplified Ajax'. Hijax was proposed by
>   Jeremy Keith as a technique for building web applications that
>   degrade gracefully by only using AJAX techniques to 'hijack' form
>   submissions and responses, updating the DOM to reflect the results of
>   the request/response cycle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijax

---

I'm just starting a hobby project of mine, and I decided it would be interesting to "hijax" pretty much everything. I'm using sails.js(which uses express) as my backend framework, and no framework on the client side.

---

Hijaxing regular links (`GET` requests) is pretty straightforward, but `POST` requests are a little bit more complicated, since they **modify data and have to respond whether the action was successful or not, and also (sometimes) give back the updated view with the updated data.**

The way I'm handling `POST` requests (form `POST`s) is...

1. On the client side, I check for clicks on any element that has a `type=submit` attribute and belongs to a `form`.
2. I send an **AJAX request** to that element's **form action**.
3. **On the server**, the controller of that action's route modifies the database, and if it is succesful, it sends a **res.redirect()** with the desired URL to be loaded after the form is sent.
4. Back on the client side, when the server responds with the redirect, my hijax script **inserts the 'redirect' response HTML into the document** (since res.redirect() actually sends HTML).

---

**[CLIENT]** Here's an example of the client side code that sends form data and inserts the response HTML:

```
function ajaxSend(form) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            var response = xhr.responseText;
                UI.body.innerHTML = response;
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.open("POST", form.action, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

**[SERVER]** And here's an example of the type of controller this AJAX script communicates with when it's a POST request:

```
        User.update({ id: req.user.id }, {

        }).exec(function done(err, updated) {
            if(err) return res.redirect('/profile?err');
            return res.redirect('/profile');
        });
```

---

All of my normal `GET` routes already handle what data to serve depending on if they are being requested from AJAX or not. So that's why `res.redirect()` also returns the appropriate HTML (a partial bit or the full thing). I'm thinking that if there's an error with validation/data posting, I could also send flash messages along with the redirect.

So my question is, **is it okay to rely on res.redirect() to send back the HTML I want rendered after the database modification is done?** I mean, after all, the redirect instructions are contained within a header, and that isn't very reliable, or is it? I realize I could also return a view, but then that'd be having to replicate code that other controllers already do.

Thanks.

---

Comment: Do you mean "hijack"?

Comment: Hah no, I really do mean "hijax". It sounds funny, but the term exists. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijax): `"Hijax is a term for the application of progressive enhancement to AJAX.  It was proposed as a technique for building web applications that degrade gracefully by only using AJAX techniques to 'hijack' form submissions and responses"`

Comment: "I realize I could also return a view, but then that'd be having to replicate code that other controllers already do." - wrt that, using DI/Components can eliminate many such cases of duplicate code. Shoving on the logic into the controller isn't that much better than shoving all the logic into a Webform codebehind..

Comment: I don't use sails.js, but I can tell you my general approach to this.  On the server side for normal requests, the process is basically (1) validate inputs, (2) read/write some DB, (3) compute some values, (4) use a template to put those values in a new page to send.  The way I implemented "hijax" is: if the request is AJAX, step (4) above is replaced with (4) put values in a json object and return it.  Then the client side uses those json values to know what to update on the page.